# create Geoserver SQL Views

Tags: geoserver, sql

I want to create an SQL View in my local Geoserver (2.4.4), acccording to the handbook.
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html

They say:

> In order to create a SQL View the administrator invokes the Create new layer page. When a database store is selected, the usual list of tables and views available for publication appears, A link Configure new SQL view... also appears:

My Questions:

Where can I find the "create new layer page"?
Where do I select a database store then.

I simply cannot find any of these.

Comment: Have you seen this help doc: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html

Comment: yes:  look above.

Answer (score 2):

Open your GeoServer Admin Instance at `http://yourhost:8080/geoserver/web/` and log in ..

To use SQLViews, you must have a database configured and available with data in it .. usually PostGreSql, and you must have already configured a Database DataStore to use SQL Views.

Select layers -> Add new Resource (green + button at the top)

In the drop down list of datastores, choose one of your Database Stores that you have already configured

In the text at the top of the next page that opens up, you will see a link to `Configure new SQL view...`